# Why I get undefind data outside of subscribe in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular and trying to fetch data, then assign the data to passToChild variable to use it outside subscribe, and pass it to child component, but when I use this variable outside subscribe, I get undefined.
I know this because of Subscribe(),  will execute asynchronously, so when I try to pass it to child has no data because subscribe hasn't finished yet
Is there a way to allow passToChild variable to get data, then pass it?

service

```
  getData(): Observable<any> {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  return this.http.get<any>(url)
  }
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FetchdataService } from "./services/fetchdata.service"
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit  {

  passToChild;
  constructor(private Fetchdata: FetchdataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.Fetchdata.getData().subscribe((data) => {
          this.passToChild = data;
          console.log(this.passToChild) // Show all data

        });
        console.log(this.passToChild) //undefined
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<app-child [test]="passToChild"></app-child>
```

Could someone please explain to me how I can use what's inside the subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*ngIf` on the `app-child` so you control component attached or detached, and by using this way you need to catch the returned observable from your serves and unsubscribe it manually

```
<app-child *ngIf="passToChild" [test]="passToChild"></app-child>
```

or you can directly interact with the returned observable from your service

```
passToChild$: Observable<any>;
constructor(private Fetchdata: FetchdataService) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.passToChild$ = this.Fetchdata.getData();
}
```

and in your template use async pipe, using this way you do not need to unsubscribe observable in your hand

```
<app-child *ngIf="passToChild$ | async as passToChild" [test]="passToChild"></app-child>
```

Comment: @ Ali Alkhatib  many thanks, it finally works. I'm having trouble understanding rxjs.

Comment: @Rakh Most welcome, the basics are simple and I recommend you spend some time understanding it if you want to move on with angular :)